# Cell height equal to image width

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I've created cell with 4 different imageViews where i've created dynamic constraints, so they will change the width and height equal to the device size, but since cell is not dynamic then it won't change the height of the imageView. Therefore I want to set the cell Height equal to the image Width, so the images always will have the same width and height.

In heightForRowAtIndexPath, I've tried to return following, but this is giving me an error: (lldb)

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ImageViewCell

return cell.image1.frame.width
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant call cell object within `heightForRowAtIndexPath` because it creates infinite loop as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. secondly, adjust `width` using constraints
as function name clearly indicates that it is for height.

If you are sure about the height of the control, then use this

```
return 90.0 //its optional if height is fixed
```

else
add `constraints` for `top`, `bottom`,`left` ,`right`, `width` and `height` constraint, and use >= condition for height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use to Tableview's Delegate to set its cell height. maybe you can try somethin like that:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        return image.frame.size.width;
        break;
    case 1:
        return image.frame.size.width;
        break; 
    default:
        return 44;
        break;
     }
}
```

I think you need to get the size of `UIimage` from your datasource. not from your cell.